# Term for a similar word that cannot stand for it in every context?

Tags: terminology, semantics, synonymy, lexical-relations

I once learned a term meaning a similar word that cannot stand for it in every context, i.e. a synonym that doesn't work in *every* instance the original word can (*not* a hypernym). What is this term?

Comment: Well many argue that full synonyms don't exist, so the term could just be synonym ;)

Comment: How about hyponym?

Comment: I guess one example of such situation could be when two verbs are synonyms but use a different syntax, one being transitive and the other intransitive. A classical example in French is *se souvenir* (intr) and *se rappeler* (tr), both meaning *to remember*. Is that what you have in mind, or something more semantical.

Comment: I agree with curiousdannii, it looks like you're talking about synonyms.

Comment: According to wikipedia, the answer could be hyponym as suggested by @GastonÜmlaut if the issue is semantical rather than syntactical.

Comment: Hyponym is pretty much the same idea as hypernym, i.e. there is an overlap of a subset of a word's semantic range. I distinctly remember learning an actual term for this, I just can't remember what it is. It isn't hypo/er/nym.

Comment: Hypnomy isn't just overlap in a subset, the entire semantic range of the hyponym is included within the semantic range of the hypernym, so it seems to me it's one possible answer to your question. The only other possible answer I can think of (given your question's wording) is 'partial synonym', a term whose semantic range overlaps partially with that of another term. Of course it's often said that there are no perfect synonyms, in which case all synonyms are, at best, partial.

Comment: Perhaps it was a philosophical term rather than a linguistic one.

Comment: I found it! The word I was looking for is [plesionym](ftp://ftp.cdf.toronto.edu/pub/gh/Hirst-NearSynonyms-95.pdf).

Comment: @Daи that word is very uncommon. 'Synonym' or 'near synonym' would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is **near-synonym** or **plesionym**. According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plesionym), it means

> A word that is almost a synonym but which has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: That appears to be a very uncommon words. Who coined it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for reproducing [my comment](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8834/term-for-a-similar-word-that-cannot-stand-for-it-in-every-context?noredirect=1#comment21298_8834) as an answer.

Comment: @Daи Why assume libcub reproduced your comment? People who know an
answer will often give it without reading all the comments (it
happened to me is a similar situation), especially when some of the
comments appears only on request, as is the case for yours. They may
sometimes forget to read all answers, and that is a fault if the
correct answer is already there. But comments are not answers. You
should have written your answer as an answer, not as a comment. As it
is, libcub is first to answer correctly and should thus be accepted.

Comment: @babou my thankfulness was genuine, not snarky. And I presume he did see my comment since he linked to the exact paper I referenced in my comment, but if not, no big deal. I'm still glad it was posted as an answer regardless.

Comment: @Daи Sorry and apology for misinterpreting. Very fairplay on your part.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, "true synonyms" do not exist. At least not when taking pragmatics into account. If we ignore pragmatics for a moment, we could claim that, e.g., *At most five people will come to the party* and *Less than six people will come to the party* are (truth-conditionally) equivalent. In any case, even this example is not uncontroversial.

Returning to the question: The term used (at least in semantics) is that of a *near synonym*. For example, entities in the world that may be referred to both with mass and count nouns (e.g. *foliage* and *leaves*, *coins* and *change*, *clothes* and *clothing*, *footwear* and *shoes*). While roughly interchangeable, they behave, morphosyntactically, according to their mass/count role (e.g. pluralization is only licensed for the count expressions in each pair listed above).